# How to change a specific string in a character Array?

Tags: c, ubuntu

This is my very first question so it might look a bit ugly.

Problem: I have to be able to read and replace names.

My solution:

```
*char NamesArray[] {"name1", "name2"};
```

so I could just enter in names and read them through pointers.
Although reading full names requires me to make a loop now.
This does bring another problem and that is, not being able to change names when program is running.

How do I change names and how do I print the new list of names after one or more names changed?

- Its not a must to have names already in the array.
- If its possible with a different array or/and library, that's fine.

Name inputs are given through terminal but that's probably not a surprise.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your code won't even compile; can you show more context?

Comment: This question is not clear. The code snippet is not a valid code as well. Please post some  code (aka [mcve]) and explain what you want to be added to it or what is not working.

Comment: Remember that it's not allowed to modify literal strings. They are, in effect, read-only. That's why it's recommended to use `const char *` for pointers to string literals (to help the compiler catch these problems instead of them happening at run-time).

Comment: In an array of pointers to string literals, you have to change the pointer value, to point to another string.

Comment: So what im understanding from this is, I should create a new string and point the name to the new string instead of editing an older one (since its not possible anyways!).

Comment: You can use an array of arrays to create modifiable strings. Like `char NamesArray[][30] = { "name1", "name2" };`